# Error C2280: attempting to reference a deleted function (unique_ptr)

Tags: c++, c++11

I went through some old code that used raw pointers and changed them to `unique_ptr`s instead. Now, when I try to compile the code, I get this error message:

> Error  1   error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function  d:\visual studio 2013\vc\include\xmemory0

The compiler output about the situation is huge - to save space in this question, see it [here](http://pastebin.com/J4xJi3Uy).

As far as I can tell, it has something to do with the way I use the unique pointers. It starts from here (level.h, lines 65-66):

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<Enemy> PEnemy;
std::list<PEnemy> m_enemies;
```

Now, the next clue I get in the compiler output is the line 47 in basesource.cpp:

```
std::list<PEnemy> enemies = Game::LEVEL->getEnemies();
```

Why does this cause problems? How can I fix the error?

Comment: The error is reminding you that `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`unique_ptr`s cannot be copied; only moved! But since `std::list` should be able to move them around internally, your only problem should be that assignment you're performing to the list itself.

Can you *move* the list?

- `std::list<PEnemy> enemies = std::move(Game::LEVEL->getEnemies());`

Or use a reference to it instead?

- `const std::list<PEnemy>& enemies = Game::LEVEL->getEnemies();`

If not (and it will depend on the return type of `Game::LEVEL->getEnemies()` as to which, if either, of the above solutions you can use), you're going to need to do a deep, deep copy *or* switch to `shared_ptr` instead.

This all may seem to be a hindrance, but it's actually doing you a favour by keeping the rules regarding ownership of your pointees strictly enforced.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I was using a reference of the std::list - the getEnemies() is returning `const std::list<PEnemy>&`. Doesn't that produce a const reference? Or am I completely lost here?

Comment: @manabreak: `const std::list<PEnemy>&*` isn't valid! There are no pointers to references. Even if you were to return `const std::list<PEnemy>&`, you're still dropping the reference and attempting to copy that list by assigning it to a brand new one (called `enemies`). Perhaps `const std::list<PEnemy>& enemies = Game::LEVEL->getEnemies()` can help you?

Comment: The asterisk was a typo, I fixed it, but you already sneaked past it. :p