# Unique_ptr in a vector as an attribute of a struct

Tags: c++, struct, unique-ptr

I am having a little trouble in C++ with a struct that shall contain a unique_ptr.
A part of the struct is

```
    struct test {
        std::vector <std::unique_ptr<function>> allFunctions;        
    }
```

where

```
     function
```

is another struct. I always get C2280 attempting to reference a deleted function

As you might suspect I am quite new to C++ and have not much experience.
And i HAVE TO use an unique_ptr, since this is part of an exercise.

Thank you already for your help! :)

Comment: On which line do you get that error? I guess its not in the three you show.

Comment: it says the error occurs in the standard library memory in line 920

Comment: You may want have a look at [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26505899/error-c2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted-function-unique-ptr).

Comment: Thank you, I looked at it earlier but I don't really understand what that means for me or what I should do

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the code that uses `test`, i.e. the code that you didn't show.

`std::unique_ptr` is by definition not copyable (it's *unique*!). That makes your whole structure not copyable.

If you attempt to copy `test` somewhere, the compiler will tell you that there is no `std::unique_ptr::operator =`, which is needed for copying.

For example:

```
test x;
test y = x;  // Copying. Error C2280
```

Or

```
void someFunction(test x) {}

int main() {
    test x;
    someFunction(x);  // Copying. Error C2280
}
```

`Error  C2280   'std::unique_ptr<function,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

The solution is to avoid copying `test`. You can achieve that by passing it by reference.

```
void someFunction(test& x) {}

int main() {
    test x;
    someFunction(x);  // OK
}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I think now I got it! :)